# How can I run `bundle outdated` without the gems actually installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a folder with a Gemfile, I can generate the `Gemfile.lock` with `bundle lock`, and I want to get the available updates through `bundle outdated` but without the need of having all the gems listed in my `Gemfile.lock` installed on my system.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 4):

`gem outdated` prints outdated gems without installing them.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to install anything, but it will have to download any referenced Git repositories to gather any related version information from them.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the gem installed that are in the gemfile installed on my system the command `outdated` exit early without results: ` Could not find gem 'sidekiq' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

Comment: The `bundle` command has to verify versus not only the `.lock` file but the gems that are actually installed. I'm not sure you can skip the installation check.

Comment: @tadman it is what I feared... guess I need to manually parse the .lock file and check if there are new versions manually

Comment: It's not as easy as you'd think since Bundler does a lot of dependency math to see if it's possible to upgrade. Just because there's a newer version published on Rubygems doesn't mean it's a valid option for your project. You could try and patch this functionality in by leveraging the dependency tree code and make a pull request if you're feeling adventurous.